# Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempt to read past end-of-file in standard input??? With TextIO

Tags: java

This Java code keep attempting to read past the end of input file. Why this could be happened? How to fix this?

it gives the error
illegal argument exception an atempt to read past end of line
at line 50 which is :

```
            request=TextIO.getln();
```

How could i fix it?
thanks it advance

```
public class HotelTUI {

    private static HotelTUI hotelTUI;
    private static Hotel hotel;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hotel= new Hotel("U Parkhotel");
        hotelTUI= new HotelTUI("U Parkhotel");
        hotelTUI.start();

    }

    public void printHelpMenu() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Hotel booking system of the U parkhotel");
        System.out.println("Commands:");
        System.out.println("i name . . . . . . . . . . . . check in guest with name");
        System.out.println("o name . . . . . . . . . . . . check out guest with name");
        System.out.println("r name . . . . . . . . . . . . request room of guest");
        System.out.println("a name password. . . . . . . . activate safe,password required for PricedSafe");
        System.out.println("b name nights. . . . . . . . . print bill for guest (name) and number of nights");
        System.out.println("h  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . help");
        System.out.println("p  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . pring state");
        System.out.println("x  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . exit");
    }

    public HotelTUI(String hotelName) {
        this.hotel=hotel;   
    }


    public void start() {

        boolean exit=false;

        String parameter;

        while(exit==false) {
            String request;
            String paramTwo="";
            request=TextIO.getln();
            String[] splitted = request.split(" "); //split where there is a space
            if ( request.length() > 1) {
                parameter=splitted[1];
                request= splitted[0];
                if(request.length() > 2) {
                    paramTwo = splitted[2];
                }


                if (request.length() == 1) {    
                    switch(request) {
                    case "i":
                        System.out.println("Guest "+parameter+" is checked into room 101");

                        hotel.checkIn(parameter); //parameter is guest name 
                        break;
                    case "o":
                        System.out.println("Guest "+parameter+" successfully checked out.");
                        hotel.checkOut(parameter);

                        break;
                    case  "r":
                        hotel.getRoom(parameter);
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        if(parameter==null) {
                            System.out.println("Please give a correct name");
                            
                        }
                        if(hotel.getRoom(parameter)==null) {
                            System.out.println("There is no room with this customer");
                        }
                        //paid safe
                        if(hotel.getRoom(parameter).getSafe().getClass().equals(PricedSafe.class)){
                            if(paramTwo==null) {
                                System.out.println("Please give a correct password");
                            }else {
                            
                        PricedSafe safe =( PricedSafe) hotel.getRoom(parameter).getSafe();
                        safe.activate(paramTwo);
                        if(safe.isActive()) {
                            System.out.println("Safe is active ");
                        }else {
                            //System.out.println("Activated!");
                        }
                            }   
                        }else {
                            //basic safe
                            hotel.getRoom(parameter).getSafe().activate();
                        }
                        break;
                    case "b":
                    
                        if(parameter==null || paramTwo==null) {
                            System.out.println("Please give the proper amount");
                        }
                        if(hotel.getRoom(parameter)==null) {
                            System.out.println(parameter+" customer does not have a room");
                        }
                        hotel.getBill(parameter, Integer.parseInt(paramTwo), new SysoutPrinter());
                        break;
                    case "h":
                        printHelpMenu();
                        break;
                    case "p":
                        System.out.println(hotelTUI.toString());
                        break;
                    case "x":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;

                    }
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Enter correct command please! You can use option 'h'to see the full menu again ");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reads all the characters from the current input source, up to the next end-of-line. The end-of-line is read but is not included in the return value. Any other whitespace characters on the line are retained, even if they occur at the start of input. The return value will be an empty string if there are no characters before the end-of-line. When using standard IO, this will not produce an error. In other cases, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown if an end-of-file is encountered.

See also https://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes7/TextIO_Javadoc/TextIO.html#getln().

I suspect you tried using the text-io library of beryx (https://text-io.beryx.org/). You can find more documentation about it on their website.